# how to use react-redux provider inside next.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i want to use react-redux lib to make easy dispatch or subscribe a store.
is there any way to do this? I do not know where should place the provider of react-redux.
in this case i create my redux store as simple react project not with next-redux-wrapper